# What are the segmentation patterns for sentiment analysis

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to implement sentiment analysis for customer reviews.I found some patterns like POS tagging, bigrams models.I need to know more ways which i can use to segment sentence to find it is negative or positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two specific approaches to do sentiment analysis.

1- Corpus-based approach : In this approach machine learning is used on text with any features that is valid on text such as n-grams, tf-idf, term frequency, term occurrence. You can combine feature results with weights as well.

2- Lexicon-based approach : In this approach a sentiment lexicon such as [SentiWordnet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it) or [SenticNet](http://sentic.net) is employed with basic rules to find the sentiment polarity of sentence. POS tagging is mostly used in this approach.